# Importing MatButtonModule does nothing

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

I am building an Angular app using the Material library.

I want to use the material button module package.

I import it in **app.module.ts** like this (abbreviated example):

```
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

...

  imports: [
MatTableModule,
MatCheckboxModule,
MatButtonModule,
],
```

Now, when I go to **home.component.html** I get Material Tables and Checkboxes to work just fine.

My IDE also detects the rest of the Material modules automaticly. But for some reason the Material Button just does not exist for it.

```
<mat-table></mat-table> //works
<mat-checkbox></mat-checkbox> //works
<mat-button></mat-button> //does not work
```

Am I missing something here?

I am using Angular 9.0.3 and Material 9.1.0

Comment: try with  <button mat-button>Basic</button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material button is a directive, so selector looks like:

```
button[mat-button]
```

Try change your code to `<button mat-button>Basic</button>`

https://material.angular.io/components/button/api